# Subtracting the same value from a single column in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with two columns and want to add a value (125) to each item in the second column *only*.
This is the array called arr

```
array([[124609.,    474.],
       [ 46225.,    353.],
       [ 50176.,    340.],
       ...,
       [ 51984.,    349.],
       [ 46225.,    353.],
       [ 50176.,    340.]])
```

I tried the following: selecting only the 2nd column and subtracting 125 from it

```
arr=arr[:,1]-125
```

But when I go to print
`arr` out it doesn't yield the 2d array as expected

```
array([[124609.,    349.],
       [ 46225.,    228.],
       [ 50176.,    215.],
       ...,
       [ 51984.,    224.],
       [ 46225.,    228.],
       [ 50176.,    215.]])
```

it yields only a 1d array

```
array([349., 228., 215., ..., 224., 228., 215.])
```

Comment: try `arr[:, 1] -= 125`

Comment: @MechanicPig unless this topic already exists, why not make your comment an answer, since it might be a question others might have :)